# Combining Strings into a datestamp

Tags: sd-card

I'm creating a weather station / environmental datalogger and am saving my data to a SD card Breakout. The SD card works fine but I would like to name the files I am saving on it after the date when the readings were taken.I've tryed multiple things but I can't work out how to combine the date from my RTC and put them in a file name. I've tryed this:

```
dataFile = SD.open(String(now.day()) + "-" + String(now.month()) + "-" + String(now.year()) + ".csv",FILE_WRITE);
```

But this gives me an error -

```
char dateName[13] = {String(now.day()) + "-" + String(now.month()) + "-" + String(now.year()) + ".csv"};
dataFile = SD.open(dateName,FILE_WRITE);
```

But this gives me this error:

```
 cannot convert 'StringSumHelper' to 'char' in initialization
```

Help! How do I do this?

Comment: How many problems can you detect here: "char dateName[13] = {String(now.day()) + "-" + String(now.month()) + "-" + String(now.year()) + ".csv"};"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*EDIT: As noted by Klaus Warzecha, the SD library may only support 8.3 format filenames (i.e. 8 characters for the name, 3 characters for the extension). The solution may in fact be to ensure that the years is only 2 digits, resulting in names like: `20-12-14.csv`*

---

From what I can see in the SD library code, the `open()` method isn't designed to accept a `String` object as a parameter. It only wants a plain old [C-style string](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/String) (which means a `char` array). That explains why your first example doesn't work -- it's trying to pass a `String` object.

The second example unfortunately is invalid C++. You simply can't initialise an array like that. What you want to do instead is to build the `String` object, then extract the characters out using `String::toCharArray()`.

Something like this should work:

```
String filename = String(now.day()) + "-" + String(now.month()) + "-" + String(now.year()) + ".csv";
char str[16] = {0};
filename.toCharArray(str, 16);
dataFile = SD.open(str, FILE_WRITE);
```

I'm not sure what your `now.year()` returns; i.e. if that's a 2 digit or 4 digit year. I've assumed 4 digits, so I've made the `char` array big enough for 15 characters in total, plus an extra null terminator (which is essential for C-style strings).

Comment: The SD card doesn't get files saved onto it when using this.

Comment: Can you check if it works when you write the filename manually? E.g.: `dataFile = SD.open("test.csv", FILE_WRITE);`

Comment: @SquarePie I tested the filename code just now, and it works as expected. I suspect the problem must be somewhere else in your code (or possibly the hardware).

Comment: @SquarePie I suggest you create a new question for this more specific SD write issue; it seems to me (but it's you to decide) that the current question has been correctly answered.

Answer (score 2):

Is this based on the [SDFat](http://code.google.com/p/sdfatlib/) library?

Then you have to live with short 8.3 filenames for the moment.

Comment: It looks like this applies to the core SD library too. I hadn't noticed that. Well spotted.

Answer (score 1):

In your second case, you need to break the initialization into two lines and use [toCharArray()](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringToCharArray) as shown:

```cpp
char dateName[13];
String(String(now.day()) + "-" + String(now.month()) + "-" + String(now.year()) + ".csv").toCharArray(dateName, 13);
```

Then, you can move ahead with opening the file.

The problem you are seeing is quite literally what the error message says. An initialization of a character array requires a character array. It cannot be initialised with a string object.

Comment: The SD card doesn't get files saved onto it when using this.

Comment: @SquarePie That's odd. Maybe there is something wrong  elsewhere, in the code, or in the hardware?

Answer (score 1):

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
String filename = String(now.month()) + "-" + String(now.year()) + ".csv";

char str[16] = {0};

filename.toCharArray(str, 16);

File dataFile = SD.open(str, FILE_WRITE);
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: Add some explanation to your code only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well:

```
  char buffer[15];
  snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%02d-%02d-%04d.csv", now.day(), now.month(), now.year());
```

After `snprintf` call, `buffer` contains the name of the file.

This solution use constant fixed space in RAM (just 15 bytes for buffer), while all others solutions demands tons of RAM for creating multiple String objects.

And it's faster, because it only do the format part, minus all creations, conversions, and deletion using String.

Finally, generated names are always the same length, from 1-1-2018 thru 31-12-2018.

Don't use String with Arduino.